# How to set timeout for svn update?

Tags: linux, ssh, svn

I have about hundreds of server(all has its own working copy), fabric(python ssh tool for administration) will issue multiple `svn update` to those machines, many commands (10% machine) return `Connection reset by peer`. The svnserve's log show not enough updates(for example, svnserve's log show only 4 update for 11 `svn update`, see [docs](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.serverconfig.operational-logging.html) here).

I want to know how to set backlog for svnserve, and how to set time-out for svnserve(svn protocol), and how many connection can be served concurrently by svnserve command?

Is this [http-timeout](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.confarea.html) for http or svn protocol?

Comment: To me it looks like it is only for http protocol. I do not see any effect of http-timeout option on my svn timeout, which is way to big.